# python drop row if for particular strings only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove the rows when column C has stand alone data value set to be ",". The code below is removing all the rows that contains ',', how do I just remove value =',' and not delete anything else?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2,3,4,5,6], C=["Doe, John",",","Driver,A","Matt,", ",",","]))
df2
df2[~df2.C.str.contains(",")] # removes everything
```

Input:

```
A   C
1   Doe, John
2   ,
3   Driver,A
4   Matt,
5   ,
6   ,
```

Output Needed:

```
A   C
1   Doe, John
3   Driver,A
4   Matt,
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you don't want the exact character ',' you can do:

```
    df2[df2.C != ',']
```